# request.getInputStream() in Django

Tags: java, django, request

I am doing a Django project. I want to convert this java code into python.
http://www.chemaxon.com/marvin/sketch/saveimage_jsp.txt

My problem is I cannot find something similar to request.getInputStream() in Python. This function is needed in order to get the temporary file from memory. I know that there is request.FILES in Django. But this file I want to get is not from user's computer. It is from the memory (which was created by a java applet).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I just want to run the code of chemaxon in my django project. Hence, any idea about how to run jsp in Django is also appreciated!

Comment: Not nearly enough context. How is the image being created? How is the applet being run? How is it storing it in memory?

Comment: The image is created by a java code. This code is provided by chemaxon and by a very complex algo that I cannot describe here. The applet is run by putting it into a html page. because the image is created by an algo, and not yet save in any hard disk, it is still in memory. I need to flush it out of the memory (RAM) to save it into the server.

Comment: Er, the image is in the memory of the *user's* computer? Well, there's no way of getting at that. Imagine the security implications if your HTML page could just access elements of the client's memory.